# JQuery Array Item Other Than Last

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, data-structures

Salaamun Alekum

I Was Searching For Function That Will Return Elements Of Array Other Than Last One Using JQuery Or Javascript

```
> $(["First","Second","Third"]).otherThanLast();
["First","Second"]
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inp = $(["First","Second","Third"]);
var out = inp.splice(0,inp.length-1);
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a length to shorten it:

```js
var arr = ["First", "Second", "Third"];
arr.length = arr.length - 1;
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

#### With pop():

> **.pop()** method gives you the last value of the array. It works in **LIFO** *(Last in first out)* manner.

```js
var arr = ["First", "Second", "Third"];
arr.pop();
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: @RayonDabre That was also in my answer but i was working on one with setting length. Nonetheless i appreciate it. Thanks for pointing it.